# How to generate random numbers from defined ranges in R

Tags: r, random

I want to generate random numbers in R. Say I have some ranges:

```
20  3293601
3295601 3653454
3655454 3877785
3879785 4454406
4456406 4772139
4774139 4948406
4950406 5188645
5190645 5641009
5643009 5731188
5733188 5993268...
```

Definitely, I can first generate sequences of this ranges by `seq(start, end)` and append all these sequences together. Then I can use `sample(sequences, n)` to generate random numbers. But the thing is I have many of these ranges, say I have thousand ranges, so it is not very feasible to generate all these sequences. Is there any faster way to generate random numbers in these ranges in R?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to generate random numbers between the interval for each row of the data that you posted, where the first column represents the lower bound and the second column represents the upper bound, something like this would work.

```
ranges <- matrix(c(20,3293601,
                  3295601,3653454,
                  3655454,3877785,
                  3879785,4454406,
                  4456406,4772139,
                  4774139,4948406,
                  4950406,5188645,
                  5190645,5641009,
                  5643009,5731188), 
            ncol = 2, 
            byrow = TRUE)

mapply(runif, 100, ranges[ ,1], ranges[ ,2])
```

This will generate 100 draws between each range. You could just change the 100 to however many draws you are wanting.

### Edit

Based on your comment I'm still rather confused, but I'll try. From your example, it sounds like you're wanting the result of `sample(c(1:10, 20:30), 10)` and now you'd like to know how to do that when you have a lot more intervals. Is that correct? See if the below is what you want.

```
seqs <- unlist(mapply(seq, ranges[ ,1], ranges[ ,2]))
sample(seqs, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I want exactly. If I have two intervals [1,10] and [20, 50], how can I get 6 random numbers that equally distributed in [1, 10] U [20, 50], I write "U" means union? That is to say, for instance, we may have 3 numbers from [1, 10] and 6 numbers from [20, 50].